# How do I redirect 80 to 80?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a redirect rule :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:7080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://merchant.juspay.in/$1 [R,L]

        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} demo.juspay.in
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://merchant.juspay.in/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8080>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://api.juspay.in
</VirtualHost>
```

in apache. I need to a way to write a rule such that port `80` of my ip ( `localhost` ) shouldn't be redirected to `8443`.

How can I do that?

Comment: What's port 8443 for? what do you mean by '80' should go to 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to catch traffic coming in on HTTPS (port 443) you will need another virtualhost that listens on this port. Just use the same directory and settings (and a SSL cert) and you're good.

You don't need to do the RewriteRule. Apache will know what vhost to use to serve your files based on the protocol of the request.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache configuration is saying "listen on port 80", this is the translation of your VirtualHost:
`<VirtualHost *:80>`

So I don't think you will end up in this virtualhost if your request if http://www.yourdomain.com:8443

You need another vhost listening on this specific port (8443) or I think you can do that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8443>
```

Make sure you have the 2 differents listener setup:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8443
```

I was just reading your question again and from what I understood it's redirecting on the port 8443 by itself. It means that either:

> - You have a port forwarding setup in your router, which forward the port 80 to 8443,
> - There is an htaccess rule that is redirecting the requests to this port
> - Or maybe the PHP application itself.